# Reverse string printing method

Tags: java, string, methods, reverse

I am trying to solve the following problem but how do write the method that accepts String as an argument?

> Write a method named `printReverse` that accepts a `String` as an
> argument and prints the characters in the opposite order. If the empty
> string is passed as an argument, the method should produce no output.
> Be sure to write a *main* method that convincingly demonstrates your
> program in action. Do not use the reverse method of the
> `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` class!

So far I have solved it in a easier manner:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class ReverseString {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String original, reverse = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a string to reverse");
        original = in.nextLine();

        int length = original.length();

        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

        System.out.println("Reverse of entered string is: " + reverse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend you to go through a [basic tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

You can simply do:

```
private static String myReverse(String str) {
    String reverse = "";
    int length = str.length();
    for( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {
       reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

And in your `main`, you simply:

```
String reversed = myReverse(in.nextLine());
```

Note that the *method* is `static` because you're referring to it from a [*static* manner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) (`main` method). If you don't want it to be *static*, you'll have to access it via an *object*.

Also note that it's a good practice to always have curly brackets for `for` loops, even if it contains a single line.

Answer (score 3):

> how do write the method that accepts String as an argument?

```
public static String reverse(String forward) {
   char[] strChar = forward.toCharArray();
   String reverse = "";

   for( int i = strChar.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) 
       reverse = reverse + strChar[i];

   return reverse;
}
```

But for large string appending character with `+` operator can be inefficient. And reversing string with above approach will result in wrong for uni-code mismatches. As it reverse the code units but not character. There is actually a built-in support available to reverse a string using `StringBuilder` which works correctly:

```
public static String reverse(String forward) {
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(forward);
   String reverse = builder.reverse().toString();
   return reverse;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
public class StringUtils {
    public static String reverse(String forward) {
        String result = "";
        // Put your code here
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using *Java 9* you can implement something like this. This code works with both regular characters and *surrogate pairs*:

```java
public static void printReverse(String str) {
    // character code points
    str.codePoints()
            // character as string
            .mapToObj(Character::toString)
            // concatenate in reverse order
            .reduce((a, b) -> b + a)
            // output
            .ifPresent(System.out::println);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // regular characters
    printReverse("lorem ipsum");
    // surrogate pairs
    printReverse("\uD835\uDD43\uD835\uDD46R\uD835\uDD3C\uD835\uDD44" +
            " \uD835\uDD40P\uD835\uDD4A\uD835\uDD4C\uD835\uDD44");
}
```

Output:

```
muspi merol
P R
```

---

<sup>See also: [Is there any other way to remove all whitespaces in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67050239/15613375)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

```java
private static void printReverse(String org) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(org);
    String reversedStr = buffer.reverse().toString();
    System.out.println("The reverse of the string \""
            + str + "\" is \"" + reversedStr + "\".");
}
```

in the main call the function

```java
printReverse(original);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```java
private static String reverseString(String str) {
    String revString = "";

    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        revString = revString + str.charAt(i);
    }
    return revString;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
package dowhile;
public class Dowhile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String message = "i love java programming";
        int msglength = message.length();

        int index = msglength - 1;
        while (index >= 0) {
            System.out.print(message.charAt(index));
            index--;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
gnimmargorp avaj evol i
```