# Reverse String characters in java

Tags: java, string, character, reverse

Am trying to reverse a string using a method in java, I can fetch all the elements of the string and print them out in order via a loop, my problem is reversing the string such that the first comes last and the last comes first, I tried to find a reverse function to no avail... Here is what I have so far...

```java
private static void palindrome() {
    char[] name = new char[]{};
    String name1;
    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    Scanner tim = new Scanner(System.in);
    name1 = tim.next();
    int len = name1.length();
    for (int i = 0; i <= len; ++i) {
        char b = name1.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(b + " ");
    }
}
```

That loop succeeds in printing out the single characters from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to loop through the array backwards:

```java
for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    char b = name1.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(b + " ");
}
```

You start at the last element which has its index at the position *length - 1* and iterate down to the first element (with index zero).

This concept is not specific to Java and also applies to other data structures that provide index based access (such as lists).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringBuilder` like this:

```java
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class ReverseString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Geeks for Geeks";

        StringBuilder input1 = new StringBuilder();

        // append a string into StringBuilder input1
        input1.append(input);

        // reverse StringBuilder input1
        input1 = input1.reverse();

        // print reversed String
        System.out.println(input1);
    }
}
```

You can also modify your code to do this:

1 -

```java
for (int i = 0; i <= len; ++i) {
    char b = name1[len - i];
    System.out.println(b + " ");
}
```

2 -

```java
for (int i = len; i >= 0; --i) {
    char b = name1.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(b + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *Java 9 [`codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePoints--) stream* you can reverse a string as follows. This example shows the reversal of a string containing *surrogate pairs*. It works with regular characters as well.

```java
String str = " ";
String reversed = str.codePoints()
        // Stream<String>
        .mapToObj(Character::toString)
        // concatenate in reverse order
        .reduce((a, b) -> b + a)
        .get();

System.out.println(reversed); //
```

---

<sup>See also: [Reverse string printing method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67067763/15613375)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Added `reverse()` function for your understanding

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        palindrome();
    }

    private static void palindrome() {
        char[] name = new char[]{};
        String name1;
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        Scanner tim = new Scanner(System.in);
        name1 = tim.next();

        String nameReversed = reverse(name1);
        int len = name1.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            char b = name1.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(b + " ");
        }
    }

    private static String reverse(String name1) {
        char[] arr = name1.toCharArray();
        int left = 0, right = arr.length - 1;
        while (left < right) {
            //swap characters first and last positions
            char temp = arr[left];
            arr[left++] = arr[right];
            arr[right--] = temp;
        }
        return new String(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Am gettin an error at line 109:stringindeoutofboundsexception

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in `reverse()` method of the `StringBuilder` class.

```java
private static void palindrome() {
    String name1;
    StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    Scanner tim = new Scanner(System.in);
    name1 = tim.next();
    input.append(name1);
    input.reverse();
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the build-in function charAt()

```
private String reverseString2(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String result = "";
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result = result + str.charAt(i);
    }
    return result;
}

public void test(){
    System.out.println(reverseString2("abcd"));
}
```

see also [rever a string in java](https://www.asenview.com/reverse-a-string-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

```
String reversed = new StringBuilder(originalString).reverse().toString();
```